# Airport Transit Visa for Belarusian Nationals Residing in US

Tags: layovers, spain, belarus

My mother and I (both Belarusian citizens with US residentship) will be flying Chicago-Minsk with a 2-hour connection in Barcelona. Belarus is not on [this list of coutries](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/es/ServiciosAlCiudadano/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Documents/Listado%20II.pdf), however, Russia is. Given that Russia and Belarus are close allies, it seems odd that a restriction which applies to Russian citizens wouldn't apply to Belarusian citizens. If any Belarusian citizens transferred through Spain, did you need a visa?

Comment: Are both legs booked on a single ticket (one PNR)? https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: Yes, both are on one ticket. Forgot to say that we will be departing June 6th.

Comment: Whether or not you need a visa depends on what the Spanish government decides, not on your feelings that one country is a good friend of another so should be treated the same way.

Comment: Your link says that neither Russians nor Belarusians need transit visas for airside transit in Spain.  It says that Belarusians never need a transit visa for airside transit in Schengen, while Russians only need one in a specific case. (Specifically, Russians need a transit visa, it says, when they fly *to France* from Armenia, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Egypt, Georgia, Moldova, Turkey or Ukraine.)